# NU1101 Unable to find package DevExpress.ExpressApp.Persistent.Base. No packages exist with this id in source(s):

Tags: nuget-package, xaf

I am trying to set up packages for a WinForms XAF XPO Standard Security Application.
I used the wizard to create the solution.
Then the project updater
Then I edited the project file package references.
However when I try to build the .exe project I get

```
NU1101  Unable to find package DevExpress.ExpressApp.Persistent.Base. No packages exist with this id in source(s):
```

Even though the package shows in the references.

[image: error]

I tried checking the installed packages
[image: installed packages]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason DevExpress.ExpressApp.Persistent.Base was showing in Package Manager as installed in the Module.Win project.
I removed it and now I can build the solution.